# Java JSON save an array in a file.txt

Tags: java, json

Hey thanks for helping in my last question can please some one help me with this code and help me undestand what im doing wrong? my current code

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


public class JsonEx1 {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        try
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                jsonObject.put("Nome", "Antonio Luis");
                jsonObject.put("Idade", "24");

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                jsonArray.add("Rua: Graça");
                jsonArray.add("Cidade: Lisbon");
                jsonArray.add("Codigo Postal: 2222 333");

                jsonObject.put("Morada", jsonArray);

                fileWriter.write(JSONObject.toJSONString());
                fileWriter.close();

                System.out.println("JSON Object sucessfully written to the file!!");

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why you think you make something wrong? BTW you newer create an object named `fileWriter`

Comment: `fileWriter.write(JSONObject.toJSONString());` might be the wrong JSONObject here

Comment: I dont know it gives me an error in a lot of lines i cant really tell why im new to programming in java :\

Comment: Which errors occur?

Comment: it gives me "The method put(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type HashMap. References to generic type HashMap<K,V>  should be parameterized"

Comment: i know im using the right dependency but cant rly figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using class **JSONObject.toJSONString()** in write() method use created object **jsonObject.toString()**;

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
 try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                jsonObject.put("Nome", "Antonio Luis");
                jsonObject.put("Idade", "24");

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                jsonArray.add("Rua: Graça");
                jsonArray.add("Cidade: Lisbon");
                jsonArray.add("Codigo Postal: 2222 333");

                jsonObject.put("Morada", jsonArray);

                fileWriter.write(jsonObject .toString());
                fileWriter.close();

                System.out.println("JSON Object sucessfully written to the file!!");

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```